# Evaluating Complex Log

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $L_1$ be an analytic branch of $\log$ at $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{it:t\geq 0\}$. If $L_1(1)=4\pi i$
>
> find: $L_1(1+i)\text{ , }L_1(17)\text{ , }L_1(5)$

I know that $\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg{(z)}$; so $L_1(1)=\ln|1|+i\arg(1)=0+i\arg(1)=4\pi i$ and therefore $\arg(1)=4\pi$. How does it help me find $L_1(1+i), \ L_1(17),\ L_1(5)$?

Comment: For that branch of the argument, what is $\arg 5,\, \arg 17\, \arg (1+i)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer that's it, it is not given, can I find it by myself?

Comment: $\arg 1$ is given ($4\pi$), and on a domain, a single value determines the whole branch of the argument.

Comment: Of course you can also use $$L_1(z) = L_1(1) + \int_1^z \frac{dw}{w},$$ where the integral is along a curve from $1$ to $z$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ ti : t \leqslant 0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, it is $t\geq 0$

Comment: Since all points we're interested in lie in the right half-plane, that doesn't matter. It only changes things for $z$ with $\operatorname{Re} z \leqslant 0$.